# Obj-C, adjusting the height of my UITableview when iAds are shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to adjust the height of my table view, when iAds are shown.

I'm using the following code.

```
CGRect bounds = [tableView bounds];
[tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, 
                            bounds.origin.y, 
                            bounds.size.width, 
                            bounds.size.height - 100)];
```

I also tried frame instead of bounds.

I know 100 is bigger than the height of my ad, but it looks like its taking 50 off the top and the bottom and aligning the table in the center, vertically. Instead of taking 100 off the bottom.  My ad is shown at the bottom.

I wondered if if could be autosizing, I took out the bottom red marker from interface builder, but that didn't fix the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You just need to adjust the frame height of your table view based on iAds appearing & disappearing.

Comment: are you using a subclass of UITableViewController?

Comment: @praveen-k, how do I do that?

Comment: No not using a sub class

Comment: In your view controller are you calling `[self setNeedsLayout]` and `[self setNeedsDisplay]` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't confuse the `bounds` and `frame`.  They are similar, but very different and can result in strange things if you don't understand the difference when changing the origin of the `bounds`.  I typically only set the bounds from a frame, in order to get an initial size.  For everything else, I typically just set the frame:

```
CGRect tableFrame = tableView.frame;
CGFloat iAdHeight = 50.f;
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tableFrame.origin.x,
                               tableFrame.origin.y,
                               tableFrame.size.width,
                               tableFrame.size.height - iAdHeight)];
```

Unless you've done something weird like change the anchor on your table view, this should work.

For a good reference on the differences between `bounds` and `frame`, as well as some other awesome `UIKit` stuff, watch the WWDC 2011 video for Session 121 - "Understanding UIKit Rendering".

Comment: Thanks @larsacus I'm actually needing this code to use it along with your library :) I've pt the above code in a function so I can re-use it my other tableview screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGRect bounds = [tableView bounds];
[tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, 
                            bounds.origin.y - iAdHeight/2, 
                            bounds.size.width, 
                            bounds.size.height - iAdHeight)]; // Replace iAdHeight with height of iAd
```

Your code doesnt't work because the origin of the table view is in the middle, so you have to adjust the y value when shrinking it vertically only at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This will change a tableView's frame to make it 100px smaller at the bottom.  (you can change top, left, bottom, right this way, and use negative values to increase size back again).

```
tableView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(tableView.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0));
```

Comment: I disagree.  It does exactly  what your suggestion does - adjusting the frame bottom instead of the bounds bottom.  One difference is that mine does it an hour earlier.

Comment: I realized that after I posted it and realized he was setting the bounds instead of the frame.  `UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect` does effectively change the frame in this context.